# How to politely reject weekend work from manager?

Tags: communication

Background:

For the past 2 weekends, including the week, i have been working on and off a customer production issue.

I don't belong to infrastructure team, which is solely responsible for uptime of the platform.

I belong to a application where the core issue has been identified.

There are current architectural limitations which is bringing down the quality of our product.

For the past 2 years, i have been majorly involved in customer issues, for a specific module.

Moreover our team doesn't have complete ownership of that module.

None of my team members are aware of the overall architecture of that module, because some parts were written by another team.

I seem to realise nowadays that I'm not having life outside work and is becoming difficult with the family too.

The only reason I'm not speaking up with my manager is that I'm afraid that, some action will be taken by the manager which will impact my job and family.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. There's no "magic spell" which means that you can guarantee both not doing any more weekend work and that that your manager won't hold it against you.

Comment: The solution here is to start looking for another job.  Clearly the company you work for has no respect for work/life balance and that is a huge problem over the long term.

Comment: Can you try to ask your manager if he can rotate different team members to support this task and work on the weekend ? Did he assign only you to this weekend task ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question assumes that there is a polite way to reject weekend work. That assumption is not always valid because it depends on the country, the culture, the corporation needs, and the personality of the manager.

In some places, you could simply speak to the manager. In other places, you would need to be very strong in asserting a boundary. At one place, I had to state that I was simply unavailable for the hours that the manager wanted me to work - and I was willing to walk out the door that day to enforce that unavailability.

To speak to a manager about changing your work hours / workload, that is a negotiation. Many programmers approach such negotiations in a psychologically weak position - that of being in need and giving the psychological power to the manger. In many cases, you will need to be willing to quit on the spot in order to have any psychological power in such a negotiation. If you can't quit, then what can happen when the manager refuses your request?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is simply one of those situations where your company would like you to do extra work, and will keep asking you until you say no.

You can immediately get into the question of work-life balance whether your company should reasonably expect you to work weekends, and if they should pay you for it.

However I would always start with a really simple approach that doesn't get into complicated discussions. **Simply say that you are not available this weekend.** Tell them you have personal business which means you can't work any of the weekend, from the end of day Friday to the start of Monday. You don't have to tell them what that business is.

The desirable result of this is that they find someone else to do the work, or say that the work can wait until Monday. The best possible result is that they stop asking you completely and ask someone whose job it really is. Even if that doesn't happen this gives you the possibility next weekend of saying "Can that other person do it?" or "Is it really urgent? Last weekend's work wasn't." You may still have to have the talk about how much they expect you to work weekends, or payment, but know you have some knowledge and a reference point to start.

I also find an easy way of starting the conversation about compensation is to say to your boss something like:

> I worked all of last Saturday afternoon, do you mind if I take Wednesday afternoon off to compensate?

Giving you some time off if you worked extra is the easiest way for a company to give you compensation for extra work. It doesn't involve administration and payroll departments, who are usually less flexible. Often your boss can OK it without asking anyone else.